# Getting a property just by providing a string name

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

looking for hours now on this particular question, I hope you can help.
Following class hierachy is given:

```
public class Toon 
{
 public Skillset skillset;

 public Toon()
 {

    skillset = new Skillset();
 }
}

public class Skillset 
{
    public Skill Fight;
    public Skill Trade;
    public Skill Talk;


   public Skillset()
   {
        Fight = new Skill() { name = "Fight", value = 10 };
        Trade = new Skill() { name = "Trade", value = 12 };
        Talk = new Skill() { name = "Talk", value = 15 };
   }

}

public class Skill
{ 
    public string Name;
    public int Value;
    public int Rank

}
```

This is to provide the Syntax of Toon.Skillset.Fight etc.

Now the question:
I want to be able to randomly increase Skills, if they are in the favorites list, which is a List.

So basicly:

```
public void setSkill(string skillname, Toon toon, int value)
{
  => get property and set it to value
}
```

so that

setSkill("Fight", NewToon, 30); would set Toon.Skillset.Fight to 30.

I  hope I could explain clear enough, and I'm thankful for any input. I heard of Reflection to solve this problem nicely, but I found no answer yet.

PS: just getting a List in Toon wouldn't help, it destroys the syntax.

Comment: BTW, you have Fields in your classes, not Properties.

Comment: You could just use an indexer.          
            public Skill this[string name]
            {
                get {
                    switch (name)
                    {
                        case "Fight":
                            return Fight;
                        case "Trade":
                            return Trade;
                        case "Talk":
                            return Talk;
                        default:
                            return null;
                    }
                }
            }

Comment: true, still the final model will have around 30 fields, so tha would not feel right to me. Whith the few fields provided, you're right of course.

Comment: @LarsTech: Ah, yes, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use reflection:

```
public void setSkill(string skillname, Toon toon, int value)
{
    var field = typeof(Skillset).GetField(skillname);
    var skill = (Skill)field.GetValue(toon.skillset);

    skill.Value = value;
}
```

But, this isn't the most performing solution. You should consider using a `Dictionary<string, Skill>` as your `Skillset`.

Comment: @IvanStoev Sorry. I've fixed it now.